# How to define private class inside another class properly?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a singly linked list in javascript. Though, Linked list is working fine. I am unable to encapsulate my code properly.

```
// defining Namespace here
var LL = LL || {};

// Node representation 
LL.Node = function(data){
    this.data = data;
    this.link = undefined;
};

// Rest of linkedlist features
LL.LinkedList = function(){
    var head;
    var tail;

    this.addToList = function(data){
        var node = new LL.Node(data);
        if(head === undefined)
        {
            head = node;
            tail = node;
```

In above code the Node "class" is accessible to outsiders using the LL namespace. To avoid that I tried to put Node "class" inside LinkedList "class".

If I define Node inside LinkedList using

```
// Rest of linkedlist features
LL.LinkedList = function(){
    var head;
    var tail;
    var Node = function(data) {
         this.data = data;
         this.link = undefined;
    };
    //Rest of the code
```

I am afraid that all linkedlist objects will have memory allocated for atleast one node object.
What I want is a class inside class feature such as in java but with no memory wasted.

If there is other way where I can define private class in namespace, that will also work.

Comment: *I am afraid that all linkedlist objects will have memory allocated for atleast one node object.* -- they won't.

Comment: Your solution won't allocate a Node instance per linked list, but will allocate a function per.

Comment: Okay, I did some testing by putting public properties with default value in inner class and the printing them by method of outside class. It gave undefined. I believe you guys are right.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your constructors like that, assigning the methods to `this`, you could use a function that returns the object you want to create, using a closure to keep "private" methods private...

```
namespace.myClass = (function(){

    function myPrivateClass(){...}

    function myPublicClass1(){...}

    function myPublicClass2(){
        return myPrivateClass();
    }

    // return an object literal containing 
    // only "public" methods
    return {
        myPublicClass1: myPublicClass1,
        myPublicClass2: myPublicClass2,
    }
}());
```

The catch is, `namespace.myClass` is no longer a constructor, meaning you would call is as a regular function to get the object instead of using `new namespace.myClass()`.

[Here](https://github.com/Pamblam/jSQL/blob/master/jSQL.js) is a real-world example.

Comment: But isnt `var list1 = new LL.LinkedList();` more descriptive than `var list1 = LL.LinkedList();` ?, I believe its a matter of choice. Although I see most people in community using your way.

Comment: depends whether or not it's a security issue. sometimes exposing a method that can be called manually from say a console or browser plugin can be dangerous, in which case security should take precedence, and afaik this is the only way to emulate "private"methods in js..